# Benefits of column references without constraints

Tags: sql-server, database, db2, data-modeling, thick-client

In thick client real time applications why the constraints are not put on table's reference columns. In short, the foreign key columns are copied (added as a column) in table without constraints. 
 
What is the benefit of creating such database design?

Comment: Design you stated improves insert,update ,delete performance but with comes of risk violating data integrity..In my environment we have a third party database(around 10 TB) which doesn't have any foreign keys.In my opinion if you REALLY  are 100% sure  that you wont violate data integrity,then you don't need foreign key..

Here are some links which might help you..  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83147/whats-wrong-with-foreign-keys    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317391/is-there-a-severe-performance-hit-for-using-foreign-keys-in-sql-server

Comment: Note that the query optimizer makes use of referential constraints to evaluate statistics of related columns. Absence of these constraints may sometimes lead to suboptimal query plans.