# optimise technique to fetching data from two large tables without using join in MySql

Tags: mysql, fetch

I am working on MySQL and facing an issue in server load time. here is my table's structure and query:

I need to fetch 50 rows from `message`(more than 5.6 Million rows) table. The `message` table has attributes like (id, description, author_id, timeline_id) and the condition is, each `author_id` exist in `users`(more than 38K rows) table.

The table creation script is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_description` text() NOT NULL
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timeline_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE `messages`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` text() NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

For this, I am using following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  m.id
  , m.post_description
  , m.author_id
  , m.timeline_id
  , u.username 
FROM message m, users u 
WHERE m.timeline_id ='1868'
          AND m.id <= '28190' 
          AND m.author_id NOT IN (24974,7920,1498,9020,0)
          AND u.id=m.author_id 
ORDER BY m.id 
DESC LIMIT 0 ,51;
```

please give me suggestion to get required rows in quickest possible time.

Thanks

Comment: Not using a join is not quicker.

Comment: Why you don't want to use joins?

Comment: Please also add table creation scripts. The best way is to provide a sample in http://sqlfiddle.com/, so we can help you faster and better.

Comment: @MichałSzkudlarek I have added table creation script.

Comment: Joins aren't slow. Queries without proper indexes *are* slow. Add the proper indexes. You should index all the columns involved in the `where` statement

Comment: BTW why do you think that putting the tables without the JOIN in `WHERE` will result in a *different* query plan? The database server is smart enough to see that the two queries are equivalent.

Comment: You ask how to optimize a query (without providing the schema definitions, table statistics or an explain plan)? And insist that the solution does not use a join? Please go read some of the many questions here on query optimization.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple case. You need to use index on (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html):

```
messages.author_id
```

You do not need index on users, since primary key is by default indexed in Mysql.

Consider making use of query plan, which can help you in identifying performance issues:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-performance-explain.html

With all above setup, your query should look like*:

```
SELECT 
  m.id
  , m.post_description
  , m.author_id
  , m.timeline_id
  , u.username 
FROM message m
join users u 
 on m.author_id = u.id
WHERE m.author_id NOT IN (24974,7920,1498,9020,0)
     AND m.timeline_id ='1868'
     AND m.id <= '28190' 
ORDER BY m.id 
DESC LIMIT 0 ,51;
```

*your original query will also be faster with above index changes, however I think that using implicit joins makes query more readable.

**Edited:**

As per @Panagiotis Kanavos, thanks Panagiotis, you might have to see in query plan what else causes slowness. It might occur that you need an index on m.timeline_id also.

And of course, you need to analyze table after creating an index (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html)

**Edit2:**

You can also consider using a foreign key, but this is not a performance tool, it is an integrity concept:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

You can refer to that answer about FK and performance:
[Does introducing foreign keys to MySQL reduce performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618385/does-introducing-foreign-keys-to-mysql-reduce-performance)

Comment: An index on `author_id` won't be enough. The server will have to scan all the user's messages. `timeline_id` should be indexed as well.

Comment: @MichałSzkudlarek thanks for your answer. please tell me Does foreign key concept makes any big difference.

Comment: Foreign key is a data integrity concept, not a performance tool. I should have mentioned that in the answer. Will edit.

Comment: after using 'join', no major difference in response time. is there any technique to handle big data? which can be implemented now

Comment: Did you apply index and analyze tables?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented index on author_id in 'message' table and using join but no effective difference between the previous and current server response time.