# Fetching records from the MySQL database from 10 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

I have a database with 20 tables inside it. I want to fetch records from 10 related tables at a time, and I am using Hibernate. What is the best solution: to write a single query using join with select, or write 2 or 3 simple queries?  I want to select the better solution for my service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables are related to each other, I would try using JOINS, they provide better (much better) performance than just using nested queries.

Answer (score 1):

Perform Inner joins as often as possible when looking to combine data from multiple tables. From what I understand they are more efficient than outer joins.

[INNER JOIN vs LEFT JOIN performance in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726657/inner-join-vs-left-join-performance-in-sql-server)

This post goes in depth to explaining the reasons why.

GL

Answer (score 0):

Try to use,
like

```
        select *
        from producer
        inner join director on director .entityId = producer.producerId
        left outer join name on director .entityId = name.entityId
        left outer join address on director .entityId = address.entityId
        left outer join phone on director .entityId = phone.entityId
        left outer join email on director .entityId = email.entityId
        where producerId = 1
```