# Ignore repeated rows with SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join, data-modeling

I have a table like below.

One table for storing fruits and one for its type.

```
create table fruits(fruit_id int, fruit_name VARCHAR(255));  
create table type(fruit_id int, status VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO fruits(fruit_id, fruit_name) 
            values(101, 'Apple'),
                  (102, 'Mango'),
                  (103, 'Lemon'),
                  (104, 'Grape'),
                  (105, 'Orange');

INSERT INTO type(fruit_id, status) 
          values(101, 'Edible');
                (101, 'Sweet'),
                (102, 'Edible'),
                (103, 'Edible'),
                (103, 'Salty'),
                (103, 'Sour'),
                (104, 'Sour');
```

Now I want a output like below

```
  Fruit_id    FruitName
    101       Apple
    102       Mango
    103       Lemon
    104       Grape
```

I used `INNER JOIN` but its getting repeated rows for apple, lemon and Grapes

```
SELECT fruits.* 
FROM fruits INNER JOIN type 
ON type.fruit_id = fruits.fruit_id
```

Comment: SELECT fruits.* 
  FROM fruits inner join
       type on type.fruit_id = fruits.fruit_id

Comment: I am Sorry My Mistake i think I havent properly formatted my Quetion

Comment: Actually your requirement is unclear. So every answers may give you different result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) to ignore duplicate rows like this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.*
FROM fruits f
INNER JOIN type t ON F.Fruit_id = t.Fruit_id;
```

## [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0738/23)

Comment: With INNER JOIN the result is the same and I think is more efficient just look to this question on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726657/inner-join-vs-left-join-performance-in-sql-server). That doesn't means that your answer is completely great :)

Comment: I will correct myself "... That doesn't mean that your answer is wrong, is completely great..."

Comment: I told the opposite and I was saying what I wanted to say, that your answer is great... :)

Comment: @Amedio Actually I was confused first about OP's problem. And got it after OP posted his/her effort.

Answer (score 2):

```
select f.fruit_id,f.FruitName from 
fruits where fruit_id in(select distinct fruit_id from type)
```

Answer (score 2):

write sql like you would say it :-)

*"show me all fruits where a type exists":*

```
select *
from fruits
where exists (
    select *
    from types 
    where types.fruit_id = fruits.fruit_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT f.fruit_id ,f.fruit_name 
FROM fruits f 
INNER JOIN type t ON f.fruit_id=t.fruit_id 
GROUP BY f.fruit_id,f.fruit_name
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.fruit_id ,f.fruit_name 
FROM fruits f 
INNER JOIN type t ON f.fruit_id=t.fruit_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting repeated results because at the moment to do the inner join, it gives you the pairs between data, so is normal that a `fruit` appears more than once.

For what you have, maybe is possible to use `DISTINCT(fruits.*)` in the `SELECT` statement to solve you problem.

Hope this helps.