# Issue in query with inner join and concat() operation in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
sk_accounts      //details of user
```

- acnt_user_id
- acnt_fname       //first name
- acnt_lname
- acnt_profile_picture
- acnt_member_class
- so on........

  ```
   sk_following   //table containing details of users who are following others
  ```
- id
- flwing_follower_id //id of the user who are followed by other followers
- flwing_following_user_id
- following_date

  I want to display details of the follower based on the following Mysql code.Unfortunately it returns zero rows eventhough there are 3 rows.My query is like this:

  ```
  $query_following = "SELECT sk_following.flwing_following_user_id, 
  sk_accounts.acnt_fname,
  sk_accounts.acnt_lname,
  sk_accounts.acnt_member_class,
  sk_accounts.acnt_profile_picture
  FROM sk_following 
  INNER JOIN sk_accounts 
  WHERE sk_following.flwing_follower_id='$id' AND        sk_accounts.acnt_user_id=sk_following.flwing_following_user_id AND CONCAT(sk_accounts.acnt_fname,' ',sk_accounts.acnt_lname)='$name'";
  $result_following = mysql_query($query_following);
  $count_following = mysql_num_rows($result_following);
  echo $count_following;
  ```

Note:$id and $name contain values
Kindly help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sdespont I am sorry,I am unaware of formatting

Comment: Can you confirm that flwing_following_user_id is a reference to acnt_user_id field table?

Comment: @sdespont Ya,I have this query worked in another context without using concat()

Comment: try Applying WHERE clauses one by one..u will realize where is going wrong..

Comment: Interresting! And are you reeeeeeeeeeeeealy sure that your $name is exactly the same than your CONCAT result? Char case included?

Comment: @Irantha ya i am checking,I thinks its my fault in WHERE clause

Comment: @sdespont I have checked the WHERE clause,It is having some error.Its my fault

Comment: In which statement @AnazA get error.

Comment: @AdvaitAmin Ya in the WHERE sk_following.flwing_follower_id='$id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to completely understand without seeing sample data and desired output, but should your JOIN be on the flwing_follower_id and not the flwing_following_user_id?

```
SELECT sk_following.flwing_following_user_id,
    sk_accounts.acnt_fname,
    sk_accounts.acnt_lname,
    sk_accounts.acnt_member_class,
    sk_accounts.acnt_profile_picture 
FROM sk_following 
    INNER JOIN sk_accounts ON sk_accounts.acnt_user_id=sk_following.flwing_follower_id 
WHERE sk_following.flwing_follower_id='$id' 
    AND CONCAT(sk_accounts.acnt_fname,' ',sk_accounts.acnt_lname)='$name'
```

Good luck.

Comment: I want to display all the above data in a div.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
"SELECT sk_following.flwing_following_user_id,
sk_accounts.acnt_fname,
sk_accounts.acnt_lname,
sk_accounts.acnt_member_class,
sk_accounts.acnt_profile_picture 
FROM sk_following
LEFT JOIN sk_accounts ON sk_accounts.acnt_user_id=sk_following.flwing_following_user_id
WHERE sk_following.flwing_follower_id='$id'
AND CONCAT(sk_accounts.acnt_fname,' ',sk_accounts.acnt_lname)='$name'";
```

may this help you.

Comment: Use left join because its better than inner join. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726657/inner-join-vs-left-join-performance-in-sql-server

Comment: @Anaz A you get it about left join or not? i think its better to use left join. i also use more left join then inner join.