# Performance difference between left join and inner join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

Is there any difference between left join and inner join regarding performance? I use SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Yes, there might be difference. But why do you care? These 2 are not equivalent and will (usually) produce different results. So, use the one that is useful for your query and gives you the results you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN vs LEFT JOIN performance in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726657/inner-join-vs-left-join-performance-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is at least one case where `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` is a better option than `[INNER] JOIN`. I talk about getting the same results using `OUTER` instead of `INNER`.

Example (I am using [AdventureWorks 2008 database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/)):

```
-- Some metadata infos
SELECT  fk.is_not_trusted,  fk.name
FROM    sys.foreign_keys fk
WHERE   fk.parent_object_id=object_id('Sales.SalesOrderDetail');
GO

CREATE VIEW View1
AS 
SELECT  h.OrderDate, d.SalesOrderDetailID, o.ModifiedDate
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderDetail d
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader h ON d.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN Sales.SpecialOfferProduct o ON d.SpecialOfferID=o.SpecialOfferID AND d.ProductID=o.ProductID;
GO

CREATE VIEW View2
AS
SELECT  h.OrderDate, d.SalesOrderDetailID, o.ModifiedDate
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderDetail d
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader h ON d.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID
LEFT JOIN Sales.SpecialOfferProduct o ON d.SpecialOfferID=o.SpecialOfferID AND d.ProductID=o.ProductID;
GO

SELECT  SalesOrderDetailID
FROM    View1;

SELECT  SalesOrderDetailID
FROM    View2;
```

Results for the first query:

```
is_not_trusted name
-------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
0              FK_SalesOrderDetail_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderID
0              FK_SalesOrderDetail_SpecialOfferProduct_SpecialOfferIDProductID
```

Execution plans for the last two queries:
[image]

**Note 1 / View 1:** If we look at the execution plan for `SELECT SalesOrderDetailID FROM View1`
we see a [*FK elimination*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2009/11/12/conor-vs-foreign-key-join-elimination.aspx) because the `FK_SalesOrderDetail_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderID` constraint is trusted and it has a single column. But, the server is forced (because of `INNER JOIN Sales.SpecialOfferProduct`) to read data from the third table (SpecialOfferProduct) even the `SELECT/WHERE` clauses doesn't contain any columns from this table and the FK constraint (FK_SalesOrderDetail_SpecialOfferProduct_SpecialOfferIDProductID) is (also) trusted. This  happens because this last FK is multicolumn.

**Note 2 / View 2:** What if we want to remove the read (`Scan`/`Seek`) on the `Sales.SpecialOfferProduct`? This second FK is multicolumn and for such cases the SQL Server cannot eliminates the FK (see previous Conor Cunnigham blog post). In this case we need to replace the `INNER JOIN Sales.SpecialOfferProduct` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.SpecialOfferProduct` in order to get FK elimination. Both `SpecialOfferID` and `ProductID` columns are `NOT NULL` and we a have a trusted FK referencing `SpecialOfferProduct` table.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I'm adding some notes now but **in this case** they have the same semantics.

Comment: They have the same semantics only if there is a `FOREIGN KEY` from `SalesOrderDetail` referencing `SpecialOfferProduct`.

Comment: @ypercube: `FK_SalesOrderDetail_SpecialOfferProduct_SpecialOfferIDProductID`

Comment: Nice. There is a Connect page where one can vote for adding the feature: [Support join elimination for multi-column foreign key constraints](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/510217/support-join-elimination-for-multi-column-foreign-key-constraints)

Comment: And another related blog post: **[When row estimation goes wrong](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2012/11/26/when-row-estimation-goes-wrong.aspx)**

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - They have the same semantics "only if there is a FOREIGN KEY from SalesOrderDetail referencing SpecialOfferProduct", ***and*** the FOREIGN KEY is NOT NULL

Answer (score 7):

As well as the issue that outer join may return a larger result set because of the additional rows preserved one other point is that the optimiser has a greater range of possibilities when creating an execution plan because `INNER JOIN` is commutative and associative.

So for the following example `B` is indexed but `A` isn't.

```
CREATE TABLE A(X INT, Filler CHAR(8000))

INSERT INTO A 
SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID), ''
FROM sys.all_columns

CREATE TABLE B(X INT PRIMARY KEY, Filler CHAR(8000))

INSERT INTO B
SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID), ''
FROM sys.all_columns

SELECT *
FROM B INNER JOIN A ON A.X = B.X

SELECT *
FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON A.X = B.X
```

The optimiser knows that `B INNER JOIN A` and  `A INNER JOIN B` are the same and produces a plan with a nested loops seeking into table `B`.

[image: Plans]

This transformation is not valid for the outer join and nested loops [only supports left outer join not right outer join](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/08/16/702828.aspx) so it needs to use a different join type.

But from a practical perspective you should just choose the join type you need that will give you the correct semantics.