# inner join vs left join - which is faster for the same result?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

If both inner join and left join can achieve the same result, which one is faster and has better performance (especially on large data)?

inner join:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_B B
ON A.PK_A = B.PK_B
```

left join:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A A
LEFT JOIN Table_B B
ON A.PK_A = B.PK_B

WHERE A.PK_A = B.PK_B
```

Table A:

```
PK_A    User
1   FOX
2   COP
3   TAXI
6   WASHINGTON
7   DELL
5   ARIZONA
4   LINCOLN
10  LUCENT
```

Table_B:

```
PK_B    Message
1   TROT
2   CAR
3   CAB
6   MONUMENT
7   PC
8   MICROSOFT
9   APPLE
11  SCOTCH
```

Any ideas? How can I test their performance on a large data?

Comment: Why do LEFT JOIN if you want an INNER JOIN...?

Comment: Second one is non-nonsensical. The where clause will make your left join behave as an inner join.

Comment: You test this the same way you test anything else.  Get the time, in milliseconds before and after you run the query, and subtract.

Comment: I would point you to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726657/inner-join-vs-left-join-performance-in-sql-server) question.

Comment: check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100819/left-join-significantly-faster-than-inner-join

Comment: I ran into an issue with inner join when a database was cloned to a reporting database as part of a month-end task. Part of the reporting db setup required records to be deleted from a lot of tables to reduce overall db size. This resulted in one query that ran fine in production (only a few seconds) to take 15 minutes in reporting db. Changing query to a left join restored the speed of the query. My point being, don't just code to what the data is but allow for what it could become over time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By adding the `WHERE A.PK_A = B.PK_B` the query optimizer is smart enough to understand that you wanted an `inner join` and use that instead.
So they will have the same performance since the same execution plan will be created.
[image]
So **never** use a `left join` with `where` on the keys when you want an `inner join`, it will just be frustrating to maintain and understand.

Comment: The right answer. An outer join with conditions in `WHERE` instead of `JOIN ON` will be treated as `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @DanBracuk As I stated in my answer: _they will have the same performance since the same execution plan will be created_

Answer (score 3):

Left join and inner join solves different purposes.
You can check the performance of query by executing execution plan. It will tell What all indexes query is using, how many rows it's scanning etc.
There are very good tutorial available for the same on vendor's website.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Inner join and left join are not same.
**INNER JOIN** gets all records that are common between both tables

**LEFT JOIN** gets all records from the LEFT linked table but if you have selected some columns from the RIGHT table, if there is no related records, these columns will contain NULL.

So obviously in terms of performance, Inner Join is faster.
Hope it will help you :)

Comment: In theory, inner joins will always be faster.  In real life, I have co-workers who tell me they have observed better performance from left joins.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to retrieve.
If you want to get the data only from the left table then go with LEFT Join it will be faster but in case if you want all the data which is common in both tables then INNER Join is much more efficient than LEFT

Comment: @DanBracuk, running the left join right after the inner join - or?

Comment: @jarlh, I don't know.  They were not my observations.

Comment: @DanBracuk, I just wanted to point out that you can get misleading results depending on how you do the performance tests.