# MySQL - how to speed up or change this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I did not write this query. I am working on someone else's old code. I am looking into changing what is needed for this query but if I could simply speed up this query that would solve my problem temporarily. I am looking at adding indexes. when I did a show indexes there are so many indexes on the table orders can that also slow down a query?

I am no database expert.  I guess I will learn more from this effort. :)

```
    SELECT 
        orders.ORD_ID,
        orders.ORD_TotalAmt,
        orders.PAYMETH_ID,
        orders.SCHOOL_ID,
        orders.ORD_AddedOn,
        orders.AMAZON_PurchaseDate,
        orders.ORDSTATUS_ID,
        orders.ORD_InvoiceNumber,
        orders.ORD_CustFirstName,
        orders.ORD_CustLastName,
        orders.AMAZON_ORD_ID,
        orders.ORD_TrackingNumber,
        orders.ORD_SHIPPINGCNTRY_ID,
        orders.AMAZON_IsExpedited,
        orders.ORD_ShippingStreet1,
        orders.ORD_ShippingStreet2,
        orders.ORD_ShippingCity,
        orders.ORD_ShippingStateProv,
        orders.ORD_ShippingZipPostalCode,
        orders.CUST_ID,
        orders.ORD_ShippingName,
        orders.AMAZON_ShipOption,
        orders.ORD_ShipLabelGenOn,
        orders.ORD_SHIPLABELGEN,
        orders.ORD_AddressVerified,
        orders.ORD_IsResidential,
        orderstatuses.ORDSTATUS_Name,
        paymentmethods.PAYMETH_Name,
        shippingoptions.SHIPOPT_Name,
        SUM(orderitems.ORDITEM_Qty) AS ORD_ItemCnt,
        SUM(orderitems.ORDITEM_Weight * orderitems.ORDITEM_Qty) AS ORD_ItemTotalWeight
    FROM 
        orders
        LEFT JOIN orderstatuses ON
            orders.ORDSTATUS_ID = orderstatuses.ORDSTATUS_ID
        LEFT JOIN orderitems ON
            orders.ORD_ID = orderitems.ORD_ID
        LEFT JOIN paymentmethods ON
            orders.PAYMETH_ID = paymentmethods.PAYMETH_ID
        LEFT JOIN shippingoptions ON
            orders.SHIPOPT_ID = shippingoptions.SHIPOPT_ID
    WHERE
            (orders.AMAZON_ORD_ID IS NOT NULL AND (orders.ORD_SHIPLABELGEN IS NULL OR orders.ORD_SHIPLABELGEN = '') AND orderstatuses.ORDSTATUS_ID <> 101 AND orderstatuses.ORDSTATUS_ID <> 40)
    GROUP BY
        orders.ORD_ID,
        orders.ORD_TotalAmt,
        orders.PAYMETH_ID,
        orders.SCHOOL_ID,
        orders.ORD_AddedOn,
        orders.ORDSTATUS_ID,
        orders.ORD_InvoiceNumber,
        orders.ORD_CustFirstName,
        orders.ORD_CustLastName,
        orderstatuses.ORDSTATUS_Name,
        paymentmethods.PAYMETH_Name,
        shippingoptions.SHIPOPT_Name
    ORDER BY
        orders.ORD_ID
```

Comment: Would turning this into a view help?

Comment: show your explain plan.  the where clause looks like it will be resistant to indexes...

Comment: Run the query with `EXPLAIN` in front of it to see how MySQL's execution plan

Comment: I will try to run with explain... right now I am working with limited access to the database... I am going to request that now that I am having to add indexes,... etc..

Comment: query
  EXTRA ID KEY KEY_LEN POSSIBLE_KEYS REF ROWS SELECT_TYPE TABLE TYPE
1 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 1 StatShipOn 4 orders_fk10,StatShipOn,orders_INDEX [empty string] 4359 SIMPLE orders range
2 Using where 1 PRIMARY 4 PRIMARY me.orders.ORDSTATUS_ID 1 SIMPLE orderstatuses eq_ref
EXECUTIONTIME 15

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing you should consider is whether you really need to use left joins or you would be satisfied using inner joins for some of the joins. the new query would not be the same as the original query, so you would need to think carefully about what you really want back. If your foreign key relationships are indexed correctly, this could help substantially, especially between ORDERS and ORDERITEMS, because I would imagine these are your largest tables. The following post has a good explanation: [INNER JOIN vs LEFT JOIN performance in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726657/inner-join-vs-left-join-performance-in-sql-server). There are lots of other things that can be done, but you will need to post the query plan so people can dive deeper.

Comment: create index orderitems_ORD_ID_index on orderitems(ORD_ID); - Will this work as one index to try first?

Comment: Before you add anything I would try to post the explain plan. Also, some basic stats on the tables involved such as a rough order of magnitude for the number of records in each of the involved tables. Since you mentioned there are lots of indexes already, I would be surprised if an index on orderitems.ord_id does not already exist. If it does not and orderitems and orders are large tables, that would be a good place to start.

Comment: I ran to explain and that was the first issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like just adding the index was all that was needed.

```
create index orderitems_ORD_ID_index on orderitems(ORD_ID);
```

Comment: Was this different then what I had suggested?