# MYSQL Count and Join Query

Tags: php, mysql

Table: User

```
Color
1
2
2
2
1
3
```

Table: Color

```
ID      Name
1       Orange
2       Yellow
3       Pink
4       Blue
```

Expected Result

```
Color      Total
Orange     2
Yellow     3
Pink       1
```

Mysql Query:

```
SELECT * FROM User LEFT JOIN Color ON Color.ID = User.Color;
```

How can I get my expected result? Please help me. and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something yet yourself?  Stack Overflow is not a free homework service.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I tried but it not worked so I posted question. I never want to use this platform as bad purpose or homework

Comment: Please provide some code that you've already tried.

Comment: @ShahRushabh I have made one query and give an answer to your question. please do check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.NAME, COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM Color c
INNER JOIN User u ON (u.Color = c.Id)
GROUP BY c.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will helps you to do so. brother :)

```
SELECT C.Name, COUNT(U.Color) as Total from Color C
            LEFT JOIN User U 
            ON
            U.Color = C.ID
            GROUP by C.ID,C.Name
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you explain why you are using LEFT JOIN ?? because it can be done through INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN is costly.

Comment: LEFT JOIN will returns all records from the left table (Color), and the matched records from the right table (User). The result is NULL from the right side,if there is no match. That's why we have to use LEFT JOIN. 
in this case we can also apply INNER JOIN or Simple JOIN. @AshutoshSIngh

Comment: Please go through it's basic part of query optimization

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726657/inner-join-vs-left-join-performance-in-sql-server

Comment: yeah. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

@Shah Rushabh use group by U.Color like below and you will get your result:

```
SELECT C.Name, COUNT(U.Color) as Total from user as U 
inner join color as C on 
U.Color = C.Id GROUP BY U.Color
```