# How to improve performance of this query

Tags: sql

select * from dbo.tble 
select * from dbo.tble

Comment: Whats wrong with it? what have you tried? what does your sample data look like? the list goes on but theres no info to go on...

Comment: It's hard to tell just by looking at it. Tunning must be performed with the requiriments and schema in mind. To only thing I can tell so far is  `a.servicecenterid > ''50''` is likely to suffer from implicit casting if that column is not a char/varchar

Comment: A problem can be filtering by `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), a.CreationDate, 112)` - try to filter by `a.CreationDate` and have indexing it - HTH ;).

Comment: more questions to add to the Master Yoda list is, did you check execution plan? what are the suggested index's?

Comment: If it is possible change `JOIN`s to `Left join`s by adding a filter over null values of left table [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2726657/4519059) -HTH ;).

Comment: From your title alone I can only recommend that you remove this question and repost on code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ preferably with a lot more detail on the actual issue including the questions asked above. I can see you are a new user so dont take it personally but this is not a suitable question for StackOverflow according to the help center guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well you have a column in your select that is a subquery, this if often a performance issue. You have a string splitter which can also be an issue. But without a LOT of detail all anybody can do is guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few ideas below

1. Remove as many left joins as possible. Use inner joins where-ever possible.
2. Remove sub-query to get ISerialNumber. Get this later in wrapper query.
3. Create indexes on columns in the WHERE clause if not already existing.
4. Do not use this way of date comparison. Imagine this conversion for every row in your result set.

   ```
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), a.CreationDate, 112) BETWEEN (' + (@StartDate) +
   ') AND (' + (@EndDate) + ')
   ```

Instead, convert your `@startDate` and `@EndDate` variables to datetime and compare with `a.CreationDate`

5. Calculate these before running this query into another table variables. 
   Use those variables in the query.

   ```
   (SELECT ParamValue FROM LMG.dbo.MultiValue(''' + @JurisdictionId + ''','','',1))

   SELECT ParamValue FROM LMG.dbo.MultiValue(''' + @StateOfConvictionId + ''','','',1)
   ```
6. Check Actual execution query plan in SQL Server Management Studio. The step which is taking more cost (in percentage) will need to be taken care of.

Comment: can you please re wright for me

Comment: This depends on your tables and database, and data schema. I won't be able to do that.  But step no 4, 6, and 2 should help this query a lot, in that order.

Comment: @AlemayehuKebede really? He just told you exactly what you needed to do in order to improve it. StackOverflow is not a 'gimme teh codez' site.