# how to select COUNT in subquery in optimized way

Tags: mysql, database, subquery

I have a question about **count in subquery** in mysql database. Suppose I have a `book` table that has a `author_id` and an `author` table with `id` and `name`. I want to get author list with number of books for each author. So I use this query:

```
SELECT a.id as id, a.name as name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book b WHERE b.author_id = a.id) as count
From author a
```

This works without any problem. But I want to know, **Is this solution is best and optimized solution for such examples?** If not, Is there any better workaround for these problems?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You're missing a comma before the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` and `group by` since you will need to aggregate data when counting the number of books written by each author.

```
SELECT a.id AS id, a.name AS name, count(b.id) AS `count` FROM author a
LEFT JOIN BOOK b ON b.author_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name;
```

Using a `left join` will be better if not all the authors have books in the book table, else `inner join` will be optimal [INNER JOIN vs LEFT JOIN performance in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726657/inner-join-vs-left-join-performance-in-sql-server)