# Simulating inner join with left join

Tags: sql

I know you can simulate an inner join using a left join like this:

```
select * from a inner join b on a.Id= b.Id

select * from a left join b on 1 = 1 where a.Id= b.Id
```

I'm wondering about this one. Is it also equivalent to an inner join and how does it compare performance-wise?

```
select * from a LEFT join b on  a.Id = b.Id where b.Id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You could check it yourself. And probably modern query optimizer will figure out that these queries are equivalent. **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=36557e20706f0ab1ee6487a3cc0db274)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: @dustytrash It is not the duplicate. The case is different.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda how is the case different? He's asking the difference between a left and an inner join

Comment: @dustytrash Please read carefully the question. It is about performance. All his queries are logically equivalent so when he use `LEFT JOIN` and then `WHERE b.Id IS NOT NULL` it is the same as INNER JOIN.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda The one I posted mentions performance. How about this one?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726657/inner-join-vs-left-join-performance-in-sql-server Or is it a different case because it's sql-server versus this question (sql in general)?

Comment: +1 on the question from me. Stackoverflow should be more welcoming towards questions reviewing antipatterns and having negative statements

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to an inner join:

```
select *
from a left join
     b
     on a.Id = b.Id
where b.Id is not null;
```

Whether or not a compiler recognizes the equivalence depends on the particular database.

There is usually a difference in the potential join-paths for inner joins versus outer joins (inner joins offer the optimizer more options).  So, the performance could be different for the `left join` version of the query.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 on my local machine. I have a 10,000,000 row table and self joined to test 5 times each:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[Test] t1
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Test] t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
--Avg execution time: 1563.4000


SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[Test] t1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Test] t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
WHERE t2.ID IS NOT NULL
--Avg execution time: 1547.6000

SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[Test] t1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Test] t2 ON 1=1
WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID
--Avg execution time: 1536.8000
```

So, in a simple query they seem to perform almost identically and when comparing the execution plans, the plans were found to be the same. **I would not count on the optimizer always generating identical plans between these styles** and it is a poor way to write SQL. If it is a guaranteed relationship, use an inner join.

Comment: Please compare actual execution plans instead of time.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Edited my answer to address that