# No relationships between tables -does it affect query performance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Foreign Key improve query performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507179/does-foreign-key-improve-query-performance)

I am working with tables that have no relationships (yet the data is related). I am throwing JOIN queries between these tables. Would it improve performance if I add the relationships? (PS -I will add the relationships in the future for data integrity, right now I am working on the performance. I appreciate your help.)

Comment: I don't believe having or not having foreign keys defined does much for performance. You should have them to ensure data integrity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relationship itself wouldn't help performance, however the relationship implies that there will be a unique index on the parent table columns.  That index may affect your performance, depending on the queries you run.

Comment: THat pretty much is it. Relationship or not is irrelevant for the query optimizer - but "relationhip = index" or - "no relationship = index MAY not be there". In which case the missing INDEX may make things slow.

Comment: This is not true. The optimizer can and does use FK relationships to make decisions about query plans. Depending on the shape and size of your data, a relationship can have a significant impact.

Answer (score 2):

Missing relationships between tables can have a big impact on performance, particularly as tables get large. The optimizer is a complex piece of software that needs every bit of information it can get when making decisions, and the fact that a defined relationship exists between tables is an important fact.

For an example, see [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance/71264/).