# On Postgres databases, does relationship constraints degrade performance?

Tags: performance, postgresql, constraints, relational, integrity

This is my first post here and I've tried to do my homework.

I need to have a better way to develop Data Warehouse databases for Postgres than using Power*Architect. Here is the complete sad  history:

I work with Data Warehouse development, mostly on free/open platforms (Linux+Postgres.) All the tables I create have no relationship among them whatsoever because in DW enviroments FKs enforcement adds little to no value. This is so because I have total control of what goes into the tables. Also, when doing some maintenance (like updating or deleting wrong lines) those constraints would add extra work and so I keep them out.

To model those DWs database I must draw diagrams and it is a good practice to show which table relates to which trough a foreign key/primary key. To see the relationship helps the communication of the model to the customer and also the development of it.

However, most of the database modelers, like Power*Architect, generates code to actually create the constraints. Other than modifying the Power*Architect code myself, there is no way to stop it from doing that.

And here is when the problem really hits me: when I start evolving the model, whenever I check the current database (which I keep totally free of relationship) against my model (which is full of FKs relationship lines) to find what (tables, columns, indexes) to change, Power*Architect complains the relationships are missing and "kindly" generates the code to create them. I have to read the diff exercising a lot of mind-filtering (trying to read the code without taking in the add constraint commands) and, when applying the diff'd SQL to my database, I have to manually remove those commands.

That would not be a problem if, like on Oracle, I could command Postgres to turn off the relationship constraints. I could keep the neat diagrams on Power*Architect without worrying about the relationships in effect at the database. But I can't (and I am never going to move to Oracle.) So my problem would be solved if I could leave those constraints on all the time IF it does not significantly degrade queries to the database. I can deal with some performance loss when writing, as long as it is hovers around or bellow 10% degration (like a INSERT taking 1'06" instead of 1'00".)

So, the **questions is**:

**"Are there any significant performance loss when doing a lot of writing, some small updatings and deletes to Postgres tables with FKs relationship constraint in effect?"**

As per this posts, [Does Foreign Key improve query performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507179/does-foreign-key-improve-query-performance) and http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS-SQL-Server/A_4293-Can-Foreign-key-improve-performance.html, MS SQL Server suffers performance degradation when writting and might experience a bit of a performance gain when reading. Is that a general rule? Does Postgres behaves similarly? I have looked around and did't found a direct answer to it. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/83527/3507015 comments on NO ACTION flag. Would that do the job (I mean, have the relationships without penalizing the performance)? (Postgres has this option but as per http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-constraints.html it does not seem to take "no action" but instead does not allow any action to be taken.)

Of course it would be best to have a database designer with the same features of Power*Architect (database reverse/forward engineering, database/model comparison etc.) which allowed me to draw the lines but not require them actually created as constraints neither tried to create it any time I compared model to database.

Sorry to make it sooo long a post to ask a single question.

Comment: I have just a question: did you **measure** any significant performance loss with FKs relationship constraint in effect?

Comment: There will be some performance hit when inserting with constraints on, but you'll have to do your own measurements to see how much in your situation.

Comment: Adriano, I have not. I have not yet tried it yet. I was afraid that trying it would steal me quite some time. It is a good idea, anyway, and I'll evaluate it. Thanks!

Comment: Mike Stockdale, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a performance hit.

If you `insert` or `update` on the referencing side of a relationship, PostgreSQL must do an index lookup on the referenced unique key to verify that the relevant node exists. It only has to do this when the actual key field changes, though.

If you `update` or `delete` from the referenced side, PostgreSQL must do a lookup on the *referencing* side of each relationship that points to the key, making sure no rows currently rely on the referenced row being deleted. This results in a horribly slow seqscan unless you have an index on the referencing side - in which case it's still an index lookup, *and* you have to pay the cost to maintain an index you might not otherwise need.

You *can* disable FKs in PostgreSQL, though. They're triggers, and like any triggers they may be disabled.  You cannot do so globally, you must do it for each table, but it's quite likely that your tool won't notice that they're disabled and try to "fix" them.

Do be aware that PostgreSQL's query planner is permitted to rely on the validity of foreign keys, and if if the relationship isn't enforced this could result in queries producing incorrect results. In practice, I don't think the planner does anything much with FKs at this point (only check and unique constraints) so it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Superb answer, thank you very much! I'll try to find more about disabling the RI trigger. I'll also try to learn more about the query planner so I might be alert to casual incorrect results.

Comment: Oh, it's kind of abusing a feature, and it only works for superusers, but you can (in a session) `SET session_replication_role = replica`, which will skip all triggers. Usually you'd `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE TRIGGER ALL`.

Comment: Tahnks once more, Craig. BTW,  would this "abusing" stop SERIALS from autoincrementing? Like if a new row is added, nothing would go into the SERIAL (and/or defaults)?

Comment: Turning off the triggers worked the way I wanted (also it did not turn off the serials.) I could keep the relationships and avoid the triggering of the relational enforcement. I've got a side effect though: I can't simply truncate a table which originates a relationship. I must use a cascaded. Since Pentaho Data Integration (PDI)'s "Table Output" only does plain truncate, I circunvented this with a truncate cascade before the processing. All in all, the solution worked very well. Thanks again for so many good ideias and suggestions, Craig.