# Are there any performance (speed) benefits to using Foreign Key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have 2 schemas:

```
-- borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/808921
 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `book_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
 
 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `tag_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `book_id` int(6)  unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`)
);
 
INSERT INTO `books` (`id`, `book_name`) VALUES
  ('1',  'The earth is flat'),
  ('2', 'One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin'),
  ('3',  'The earth is flat and rests on a bull\'s horn'),
  ('4', 'The earth is like a ball.');
 
 
 
INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag_id`, `tag`, `book_id`) VALUES
  ('1',  'earth', '1'),
  ('2', 'flat', '1'),
  ('3',  'ball', '5'),
  ('4', 'bull', '4');
```

and

```
-- borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/808921

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `book_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `tag_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `book_id` int(6)  unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES books(`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `books` (`id`, `book_name`) VALUES
  ('1',  'The earth is flat'),
  ('2', 'One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin'),
  ('3',  'The earth is flat and rests on a bull\'s horn'),
  ('4', 'The earth is like a ball.');



INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag_id`, `tag`, `book_id`) VALUES
  ('1',  'earth', '1'),
  ('2', 'flat', '1'),
  ('4', 'bull', '4');
```

and now a query:

```
select * from books
inner join tags as t 
on books.id=t.tag_id
where book_name LIKE '%earth%'
```

Is the schema with Foreign Key going to be faster than the one without? Yes, I know foreign keys are not about speed - they help in validation of the values. However, I am concerned about speed in this case because my proprietary  db doesn't support foreign keys.

SQL fiddle (with fk) -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f25b99/3

SQL fiddle (without fk) -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2043b8/4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Foreign Key improve query performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507179/does-foreign-key-improve-query-performance)

Comment: @philipxy - That link refers to SQL Server.  A big difference is that MySQL _does_ create an index (if one does not already exist).

Comment: @RickJames The question is & could expected to be an old duplicate that should be closed & not answered. The given link has applicable generic content. I googled the title with 'site:stackoverflow.com', which is already more research than the question reflects. The asker can start with adding 'mysql'. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No.

It is a performance benefit in that it creates an index in one of the tables.  This *may* be a significant benefit to *some* SQL statements.  You could get the equivalent by including an `INDEX` yourself.

It is a performance burden in that it will check to make sure there is a matching row whenever an `INSERT` is performed.  Also integrity checks are performed for `UPDATEs` and `DELETEs`.

It is an integrity check as mentioned above.  Depending on what you are doing, the check is likely to be redundant with your code.